# Dynamic parameter value in OLEDB Source

Tags: sql, oledb, ssis

I had asked a question earlier this day and this is another question from me.

Well, there is my Execute SQL Task which assigns a result (single value of type int) to a parameter. After this I have a DFT inside which there is an OLEDB Source. I need to execute a stored procedure in the oledb source which should get the parameter value from earlier exec sql task resultset variable. This will give me a resultset and I need to load the same into another table.

My question is, I am not able to view the column list because of the dynamic sql and hence unable to map the destination columns. How best should I proceed in this case? Is this a good approach?

Comment: Set a default value for your  int variable which would return some results.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stored procedure was using a dynamic parameter, I used the "WITH RESULT SETS" option in the OLEDB Source and it seems to work fine